# Is there an application for soft cheese rinds?

Tags: culinary-uses, cheese

When I melt soft cheese into something, I don't use the eatable rinds, because they ruin the whole texture. But sometimes the cheese is expensive (like DOC rawmilk camembert, or handmade gorgonzola), and there is still lots of cheese sticking to the rinds, so I don't want to throw them away. On the other hand, they are too dry and unpleasant to eat them on bread or similar. I don't think they'll do well in a soup like parmesan rinds.

Does anybody know a good use for the rinds? Or should I just continue throwing 40% of the cheese weight away?

Comment: I generally just eat the rinds as a snack.. :$

Answer (score 1):

They are fantastic in veggie soups, for instance pumpkin soup.

Blend the whole thing, put back on the fire and add the cheese rinds, until molten (some pieces may remain, but it adds to the texture), very yummy!!!

It definitely works with Camembert and blue cheese, I have never tried with other cheeses but I don't see why it would not work.

Of course the amount you use it's entirely up to your taste, in general do not put the same weight of rinds that you would put in cheese, as they taste stronger.

Comment: Blended soups are one of the reasons why I have these rinds left over. In case we aren't talking about the same thing: these rinds consist mostly of mold. They are dry, they smell too strong, and they don't melt at all. They crumble in sauces or cream soups, making for unpleasant patches. I don't mind them texturewise when I am biting into cheese, but when they are swimming in a sauce, they make it worse. So I am afraid this isn't the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, so you're speaking of very old rinds I guess... Camembert usually melts pretty easily. In that case... I'm not sure what to suggest, sorry